# issue with html() when use jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

load.php

```
<h2>Envato is 3!</h2>
```

index.php

```
<input type="button" value="load" id="load_basic" />
<div id="result"  class="functions">
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });
    var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='img/load.gif' alt='loading...' />";

//  load() functions
    var loadUrl = "ajax/load.php";
    $("#load_basic").click(function(){
        $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
        console.log($("#result").html());
    });
</script>
```

in frontend, when I click the button, in chrome->console, it shows:

```
<img class="loading" src="img/load.gif" alt="loading...">
```

Question:

1. why not show:`<h2>Envato is 3!</h2>` because `.load()` already put the contents into `#result`?
2. `console.log($("#result").html());` shows result:  `<img class="loading" src="img/load.gif" alt="loading...">` , but why in frontend, when I use firebug, can not see the img element: load.gif?

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous. Your `console.log()` runs before the AJAX call completes. Put it in the callback function instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the result of the AJAX call, you have to do it in the callback function:

```
$("#load_basic").click(function(){
    $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl, function() {
        console.log($("#result").html());
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, but i still wonder why. I know AJAX is asynchronous. But why `console.log()` runs before  AJAX call completes? in script, it is after the line of ajax call. could u give me more explanation? thanks

Comment: That's what "asynchronous" means. Calling `.load()` just starts the AJAX call, it doesn't wait for it to complete.